# How to secure MediaWiki instance once containing passwords?

Tags: mediawiki

I have a mediawiki site, in which during years many password and credentials have been stored clear text inside pages.

I have removed all of this dangerous content from the current version of each pages. Off course it's not enough cause all the "deleted" content it's still inside the database.

I want to get rid of it, what is best way to do it?

I thought about 2 ways:

1. get the latest version of each page with [`dumpBackup.php`](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki/blob/master/maintenance/dumpBackup.php) and import id on a fresh mediawiki install
2. find a way to clear all historical content

I think that the first one is more secure, do you have any suggestion or additional way to obtain the same result?

Answer (score 1):

The first approach you want, using dumpBackup.php to get the latest version of each page and import them into a new mediaWIKI installation, is a safe way to remove old, unencrypted content from the database. this will ensure that only the latest versions, without the sensitive information, are available. Be sure to follow Mediawiki's export and import steps, keeping secure backups of the original data, just to ensure that no data is accidentally lost. The second option of clearing all historical content can be complicated and risky as it can affect the integrity of your site's pages and history. Therefore, the first approach is the most advisable to safely achieve the desired result. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could suppress revisions with sensitive data; see [help](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:RevisionDelete) and [manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:RevisionDelete).

You could also [export](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Export) the edited pages without history, [delete](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Deletion_and_undeletion) them, hiding them from sysops, and then [import](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Help:Import) them again. That will save you time, if the pages in question were heavily edited.

Finally, you could run [`deleteArchivedRevisions.php`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:DeleteArchivedRevisions.php) to remove suppressed revisions from the database.

Making a new *MediaWiki* installation seems too drastic.